# Getting Error if using port 80 for website build on SDL web8 and DXA 1.6

Tags: web8, dxa, dxa-1.6

Below are the Error Logs. No Image displayed on webpage because of this error. If I change the website port to any other port (say 83) then no error comes and all images got displayed on web-page. The same issue getting repeated on higher Environment also. Any idea why I can not use port 80 for my website build on DXA 1.6 ?

> 2016-12-27 06:59:13,645 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:parameters, value={CONTENT_LENGTH=[Ljava.lang.String;@8ae8b79, QUERY_STRING=[Ljava.lang.String;@71e2a307, CONTENT_TYPE=[Ljava.lang.String;@7edbbc97, PATH_INFO=[Ljava.lang.String;@9d6c378}
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,645 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:server:variables, value={SERVER_PORT=8081, REMOTE_HOST=127.0.0.1, SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1, DOCUMENT_ROOT=C:\Windows\Temp\tomcat-docbase.888027786325079519.8081\, REQUEST_METHOD=GET, SCRIPT_NAME=/client/v4/content.svc/GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport(Url='http:/mytestdomain.com/ca/en/assets/js/mtiFontTrackingCode.js'), REMOTE_ADDR=127.0.0.1, SECURE=false, PATH_TRANSLATED=null, SERVER_NAME=127.0.0.1, AUTH_TYPE=null, REMOTE_USER=null}
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,645 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:server:variables, value={SERVER_PORT=8081, REMOTE_HOST=127.0.0.1, SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1, DOCUMENT_ROOT=C:\Windows\Temp\tomcat-docbase.888027786325079519.8081\, REQUEST_METHOD=GET, SCRIPT_NAME=/client/v4/content.svc/GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport(Url='http:/mytestdomain.com/media/CareerHealthNews_tcm21-327.jpg'), REMOTE_ADDR=127.0.0.1, SECURE=false, PATH_TRANSLATED=null, SERVER_NAME=127.0.0.1, AUTH_TYPE=null, REMOTE_USER=null}
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,645 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:cookies, value={}
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,645 DEBUG DefaultClaimStore - put: uri=taf:request:cookies, value={}
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,646 DEBUG BinaryMetaPublicationResolver - BinaryVariant for path='/media/C4HIE2_tcm21-326.jpg' is :'BinaryVariant{binaryMeta=com.tridion.storage.BinaryMeta@107c17a4, binaryVariantId=BinaryVariantPK{publicationId=21, binaryId=326, variantId=null}, description='null', path='/media/C4HIE2_tcm21-326.jpg', url='/media/C4HIE2_tcm21-326.jpg', isComponent=true, structureGroupId='null'}'.
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,646 DEBUG MapperFactory - No data provided for mapping; mapping to empty custom meta
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,646 DEBUG MetaDataMappingsStrategy - Fetched meta data for URL: http://mytestdomain.com/media/C4HIE2_tcm21-326.jpg
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,646 DEBUG MetaDataMappingsStrategy - The host extracted from the url is: [mytestdomain.com]
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,646 DEBUG MetaDataMappingsStrategy - The port extracted from the url is: [null]
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,646 DEBUG AbstractRenderer - Target type is Tridion.ContentDelivery.PublicationMapping and is it collection true
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG AtomRenderer - Renderer score is 31
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG AbstractRenderer - Target type is Tridion.ContentDelivery.PublicationMapping and is it collection true
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG AbstractJsonRenderer - Renderer score is 100
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonRenderer - Renderer score is 100
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonServiceDocumentRenderer - Score of JSON service document renderer is 0
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG AbstractRenderer - Target type is Tridion.ContentDelivery.PublicationMapping and is it collection true
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG XMLServiceDocumentRenderer - Score of XML service document renderer is 0
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG AbstractRenderer - Target type is Tridion.ContentDelivery.PublicationMapping and is it collection true
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonRenderer - Start rendering entity(es) for request: GET http://127.0.0.1:8081/client/v4/content.svc/GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport(Url='http://mytestdomain.com/media/C4HIE2_tcm21-326.jpg')
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonWriter - Start structured value of type: Tridion.ContentDelivery.PublicationMapping
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonWriter - PublicationMappings has root level. @odata.type won't be written here
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonWriter - Started marshalling property: PublicationId
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonWriter - Start property: PublicationId
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonWriter - Primitive value: 21 of type: Edm.Int32
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonWriter - End property: PublicationId
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonWriter - Property: PublicationId marshalled
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonWriter - Started marshalling property: Protocol
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonWriter - Start property: Protocol
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonWriter - Primitive value:  of type: Edm.String
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonWriter - End property: Protocol
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonWriter - Property: Protocol marshalled
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonWriter - Started marshalling property: Domain
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonWriter - Start property: Domain
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonWriter - Primitive value: mytestdomain.com of type: Edm.String
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonWriter - End property: Domain
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonWriter - Property: Domain marshalled
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 DEBUG JsonWriter - Started marshalling property: Port
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,647 ERROR JsonWriter - Not possible to marshall single entity stream JSON
>       2016-12-27 06:59:13,648 DEBUG ODataMessageRouter - Sending error message for exception:
>       com.sdl.odata.api.renderer.ODataRenderException: Not possible to marshall single entity stream JSON: 
>           at com.sdl.odata.renderer.json.writer.JsonWriter.writeEntry(JsonWriter.java:130) ~[odata_renderer-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
>           at com.sdl.odata.renderer.json.JsonRenderer.render(JsonRenderer.java:70) ~[odata_renderer-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
>           at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataRendererActor.renderResult(ODataRendererActor.scala:124) ~[odata_service-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
>           at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataRendererActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataRendererActor.scala:74) ~[odata_service-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
>           at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
>           at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataRendererActor.aroundReceive(ODataRendererActor.scala:33) ~[odata_service-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
>           at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
>           at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
>           at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
>           at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.1.jar:na]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_74]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_74]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_74]
>       Caused by: com.sdl.odata.api.renderer.ODataRenderException: Non-nullable property has null value: Port
>           at com.sdl.odata.renderer.json.writer.JsonWriter.marshallStructuralProperty(JsonWriter.java:316) ~[odata_renderer-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
>           at com.sdl.odata.renderer.json.writer.JsonWriter.lambda$marshallStructured$11(JsonWriter.java:262) ~[odata_renderer-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
>           at com.sdl.odata.util.edm.EntityDataModelUtil.visitProperties(EntityDataModelUtil.java:372) ~[odata_api-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
>           at com.sdl.odata.renderer.json.writer.JsonWriter.marshallStructured(JsonWriter.java:236) ~[odata_renderer-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
>           at com.sdl.odata.renderer.json.writer.JsonWriter.marshall(JsonWriter.java:204) ~[odata_renderer-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
>           at com.sdl.odata.renderer.json.writer.JsonWriter.writeJson(JsonWriter.java:169) ~[odata_renderer-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]
>           at com.sdl.odata.renderer.json.writer.JsonWriter.writeEntry(JsonWriter.java:126) ~[odata_renderer-2.0.5-1002.jar:2.0.5-1002]

```
Caused by: com.sdl.odata.api.renderer.ODataRenderException: Non-nullable property has null value: Port.
```

If I check this line of Error Code and try to match with the outcome of `Add-TtmWebsite -Id XYZ -BaseUrls "mydxasite.com:80";`. I can see it never prints port 80 if I fetch the details of same website using `Get-ttmWesbite -Id XYZ`.

Which logically is correct no need to display explicitly port 80 in base Url but I fear some how this is making port parameter null and printing same in error message when image url is hit.

Comment: Looks like a defect in Content Service. Please contact SDL Support for this.

Comment: @RickPannekoek- I have pasted latest logs that shows the content service is fetching domain name and port no. from website URL and when website is deployed at port 80 it set port as null and then throws exception immediately after this. Is there a way if we can force content service to read domain and port of website from its conf folder files. If not then we need some patch here from SDL support team it seems.

Comment: Same Error I found reported in below threads but no solution marked unfortunately http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14563/error-on-accessing-website-dxa-1-4/14565#comment20714_14565. http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14568/dxa-1-4-not-possible-to-marshall-single-entity-stream-json#comment20706_14568

Comment: I had the same issue But fixed by going through the Topology manager setup again created the Website and Mapping correctly, also double check your micro services registration by running the java -jar discovery-register.jar read command